# AWS Cognito: immediately signed-put after sign-in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

### Context

I use booth Cognito User Pools and Cognito Identity Pools to sign-in user.

I want to achieve the simple task to sign-in a user on a iOS app, a Swift app.

My app is based on custom version of Mobile Hub Help to allow the use of Cognito User Pools. See [A Swift Sample Sign-In App (using aws-mobile hub-helper) with Cognito User Pools](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh)

There is two steps in app: first one is only launch and second one is Sign-In after user touch a Sign-In button: user credentials are then hardcoded for sake of minimality.

During the first step, user have to received an unauthorized identityId. Then after second step, user received an auth identityId.

### Behavior

Before press signin, step 1, there is 2 requests to AWS:

1. AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId
2. AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity

After press signing there are 3 more requests:

3. AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth
4. AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.RespondToAuthChallenge
5. AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId

Before request 5 — AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId — user is signed-in, as indicated by observer on `AWSIdentityManagerDidSignInNotification`.

After request 5, an IdentityId is retrieved. But immediately after user is signed-out according to observer on notification `AWSIdentityManagerDidSignOutNotification`.

What may happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

@Bruce0 led me to answer!

First, on a real device running everything worked as expected.
Second, there were a lot of errors on log:
`OSStatus error: [-34018] Security error has occurred.`

The answer was to set the "**Keychain Sharing**" capability to "**ON**" in "Target->Capabilities" on Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a look at your logs. But what you need to realize is that cognito sdk REMEMBERS stuff (session id's, identity id's, etc) using keychain and NSUserDefaults.  So when you run your hard coded test for a second time, the behavior of your test will probably be different.  If you want to start clean, go to the simulator menu and choose reset content and settings (this will clear out the keychain - which stores session stuff, and will clear out the NSUserDefaults which stores sessions that are active).

I just pushed a new version of the repo on the branch AddAllMobileHubDemos. The latest version of the repository has 3 targets defined.  SignIn, MySampleApp and Dom.  SignIn is a version of my old signin app modified to work with mobile-hub-helper.  MySampleApp is a full downloaded MobileHub app with Cognito User Pools built in.  There is also Dom, a single page hard coded signin app.

Also check out (in that same repository) the cognito-diagram [cognito-diagram.pdf from the latest push](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh/blob/AddAllMobileHubDemos/cognito%20diagram.pdf), which has some of the possible errors listed.    That version has the features I described above.

If you post the logs that might help me be more specific. There are cases where the AWSIdentityManager will log you out (for instance if you try to merge two identities... which you might very well if you are using a hard coded usrname and password and then changed them without ever logging out.)

Bruce